# Spark contextcleaner not removing spilled data from usercache blockmgr folder

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application where I load a Dataset, join it with other dataset. And then write the result to some output. I repeat the same process multiple times with different datasets. I am not doing any caching of datasets.

When the application is live for 2-3 hours it ends up filling my disk folder

```
usercache/something/appcache/application_1696806712764_495852/blockmgr-something/
```

I can see there are lots of folder created with shuffle.data and shuffle.index files.

As par [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636822/would-spark-unpersist-the-rdd-itself-when-it-realizes-it-wont-be-used-anymore) answer RDD should be auto cleaned once GC kicks in. I have tried everything

1. manually setting the dataset to null, so that no lingering referencess
2. calling dataset.unpersist (even though i was not using caching or anything but still.)
3. manually invoking GC on the driver

Based on my research ContextCleaner should have taken care or removing these files, but i don't see contextcleaner log in my application.
[image]

By enabling debug log of driver i can see that context cleanup is running and have marked shuffle files to be deleted.

```
23/11/01 20:23:36 DEBUG ContextCleaner: Got cleaning task CleanShuffle(4)
23/11/01 20:23:36 DEBUG ContextCleaner: Cleaning shuffle 4
23/11/01 20:23:36 DEBUG ContextCleaner: Cleaned shuffle 4
```

I enabled debug log on my executor and able to see

```
23/11/02 10:41:17 DEBUG BlockManagerStorageEndpoint: removing shuffle 17
23/11/02 10:41:17 DEBUG BlockManagerStorageEndpoint: Done removing shuffle 17, response is true
23/11/02 10:41:17 DEBUG BlockManagerStorageEndpoint: Sent response: true to somehostname:24399
```

still the files are present on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this questions is it depends on what config and spark version you are on.

If you are using spark shuffle service (spark.shuffle.service.enabled to true)
The shuffle cleanup code was added only from 3.4.0 from [this PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/9a7596e1dde0f1dd596aa6d3b2efbcb5d1ef70ea).

If you are not using spark shuffle service, hence SortShuffleManager gets used by default, there was a bug which got [fixed in spark 3.2.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/f340857757034ac955862b34e60322ca5ee81758). This might be the reason files might not be getting cleaned up for you.

In other scenarios, if your RDD/dataset are java garbage collectable, they should be cleaned up. The frequency in worst case is 30 min by default and can be controlled using spark config

> spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval

If you want to see what is getting cleaned up or not add below config to understand what is happening

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.rpc.=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerStorageEndpoint=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.storage.=DEBUG
```