# Is there any way to Drop pyspark Dataframe after converting it into pandas Dataframe via toPandas()

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I create Spark Dataframe using input text file of size **4GB** by using pyspark. then use some condition like:

```
df.cache() #cache df for fast execution of later instruction
df_pd = df.where(df.column1=='some_value').toPandas() #around 70% of data
```

Now i am doing all operation on pandas Dataframe df_pd. Now my memory usage become around 13 GB.

- Why, so much memory is consumed?
- How can i do to make my computation faster and efficient? #here df.cache() lead to took 10 minutes for caching.
- I tried to free up pyspark DF memory by using *df.unpersist()* and *sqlContext.clearCache()* But it doesn't help.

Note : I am mainly using Pyspark because it efficiently using cpu cores and  pandas only use single core of my machine for read file operation.

Comment: Have you tried using `del df` after calling `.toPandas()`. Check detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967109/455814

Comment: Yes i tried , its not freeing up memory.

Answer (score 1):

**Why, so much memory is consumed?**

I would say duplication of dataframe in memory, as you suggested.

**How can i do to make my computation faster and computation efficient? #here df.cache() took 10 minutes to run**

`df.cache()` is only useful if you're going to use this df mutliple times. Think of it as a checkpoint, only useful when you need to do mutliple operations on the same dataframe. Here, it is not necessary since you're doing only one process. [More info here.](https://unraveldata.com/to-cache-or-not-to-cache/)

**I tried to free up pyspark DF memory by using *df.unpersist()* and *sqlContext.clearCache()* But it doesn't help.**

`unpersist` is the right thing to do. About `sqlContext.clearCache()`, I don't know which version of Spark you're using but you may want to take a look at [`spark.catalog.clearCache()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36909862/11708983)

Although I know this does not directly answer your question, I hope it may help !

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to delete the PySpark df? :

```
del(df)
```

Comment: Its not freeing up memory i first try del(df) and after that i also tried gc,collect()